# How to set javafx transition delay in each cycle

Tags: animation, javafx, transition

I want a scrolling text display. So I choose TranslateTransition to implement my function. I want the text scrolling forever, and delay 2 second in each cycle.

this is my code

```
TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(duration, text);
    translateTransition.setDelay(Duration.millis(2000));
    translateTransition.setFromX(fromX);
    translateTransition.setToX(toX);
    translateTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    translateTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
    translateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_BOTH);
```

But I find that the setDelay method is only for first cycle. Then there is no delay in each cycle. How to set delay in each cycle?

Comment: You could create a [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html), and combine it with your TranslateTransition in a [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html).

Comment: @RonSiven, thanks. You are right.